# Where is the true northern/eastern end of the Grande Traversata della Alpi?

Tags: preparation, thru-hike, alps, italy

According to [klingenfuss.org](https://www.klingenfuss.org/gta.htm), the northern end of the Grande Traversata della Alpi (GTA) is near Valsesia (Monte Rosa) or at the Val Formazza.  Wikipedia has it start [west of Domodossola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande_Traversata_delle_Alpi) (consistent with Klingenfuss), according to [gta-trek.eu](https://gta-trek.eu/index.php/stages?start=40) the northernmost point is Alpe Devero, north of Domodossola and west of Val Formazza.  [Cicerone Guide](https://www.nhbs.com/cicerone-guides-through-the-italian-alps-book) describes a conclusion *near Monte Rosa* (consistent with Klingenfuss) and [Rother Wanderführer](https://www.rother.de/rother%20wanderf%FChrer-gta%20-%20grande%20traversata%20delle%20alpi-4402.htm) appears to place the northernmost end at the Passo San Giacomo between Val Formazza and Val Bedretto, a bit further north than the rest.

[image: Sign near Rifugio Bonasson, indicating GTA in two directions]

However, I took this photo [near the Rifugio Bonasson](https://map.geo.admin.ch/?lang=en&topic=ech&bgLayer=ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe&layers=ch.swisstopo.zeitreihen,ch.bfs.gebaeude_wohnungs_register,ch.bav.haltestellen-oev,ch.swisstopo.swisstlm3d-wanderwege&layers_opacity=1,1,1,0.8&layers_visibility=false,false,false,false&layers_timestamp=18641231,,,&E=2678392&N=1120540&zoom=9), well east of Val Formazza, high above the Agrasino, further east than any of the aforementioned sources mention the end of the GTA.  The photo indicates the GTA in the direction of Forcola di Larecchio, Bocchetta di Muino, or Alpe Lago.  Apparently, neither Valsesia, nor Val Formazza, nor Passo San Giacomo is actually the most northern/eastern end of the route (meaning furthest along from the Mediterranean).

Where is the furthest north/east on the GTA, really?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Italian language Grande Traversate delle Alpi, Vol. 2](http://www.libridimontagna.net/epages/990840766.sf/it_IT/?ObjectPath=/Shops/990840766/Products/-01081603-%5B1%5D), the GTA continues to the *Lago Maggiore*, which (unlike any other description I've seen) would be consistent with the photo I took above the Val Agrasino.  According to [a review of this book](https://www.klingenfuss.org/drim_lit.htm#bucher), the northern/eastern end would be [Cannobio](https://map.geo.admin.ch/?lang=en&topic=ech&bgLayer=ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe&layers=ch.swisstopo.zeitreihen,ch.bfs.gebaeude_wohnungs_register,ch.bav.haltestellen-oev,ch.swisstopo.swisstlm3d-wanderwege&layers_opacity=1,1,1,0.8&layers_visibility=false,false,false,false&layers_timestamp=18641231,,,&E=2697082.17&N=1102006.94&zoom=8) at the Lago Maggiore.